# How to setting cookie in clj-http?

Tags: authentication, cookies, clojure, clj-http

For example, I need to parse data from my imdb.com account. So, the task is get currently logged page. I taken the "id" cookie from browser. And make GET request, but it doesn't works.

```
(ns imdb.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
(def ^:dynamic *base-url* "http://www.imdb.com/")
(def id {"id" {:value "my_value"
               :domain "imdb.com"
               :secure true
               :max-age 3600}})
(defn get-my-page []
  (client/get *base-url* {:cookies id}))
```

I think I need to set my id cookie to clj-http.cookies/cookie-store. But how?

Answer (score 4):

`clj-http` provides `clj-http.cookies` namespace which you need to use.

[You can setup your cookie store](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#cookies), then call `clj-http.cookies/add-cookie` with your cookie extracted from browser and finally `clj-http.client/get` with setting `:cookie-store`.

On the other hand you might just maintain cookies across multiple HTTP calls as described in the documentation and just call the login page from `clj-http` directly. It will make your logic repeatable without manual steps like copying cookies from browser.

Comment: Thank you, Piotrek!
I have no idea why `clj-http.cookies/add-cookie` is unavailable when I use [clj-http "3.1.0"] and "require" for `clj-http.cookies` of course. So I'm pull source code defn to my code, but it also doesn't work:
_ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie  imdb.core/add-cookie (core.clj:35)_
My def for cookie:
   `(def zz {"zz" {:discard false,
         :domain "imdb.com",
         :path "/",
         :secure false,
         :value "non"}})`
I'm stuck with it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You need to convert your cookie spec into `org.apache.http.cookie ClientCookie` using `clj-http.cookies/to-basic-client-cookie` where your cookie spec is a tuple `[cookie-name cookie-content]`. Did you try to call login endpoint and then GET call with the same cookie store?